# How do I set the Http Header for a file in an S3 bucket using boto or another tool

Tags: amazon-s3, http-headers, boto

Using python boto, how can I modify Http Headers?

In my S3 bucket I have a file with name "shop" and since I upload it without file extension, I have to manually set the Http Header: ContentType = text/html

I want to use a python script using boto to set this header for all files that require this. However I cannot find **a method that changes the headers**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import boto
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key

ak = " ... key"
sk = " ... key"
bucketname = " ... "

c = S3Connection(ak, sk)

def setcontenttype():
    c = S3Connection(ak, sk)
    bucket = c.get_bucket(bucketname)
    keys = bucket.get_all_keys()
    for key in keys:
        ext = os.path.splitext(key.name)[1]
        if ext == "" and not key.name.endswith("/"):
            print key.name
            k.set_contents_from_string(k.get_contents_as_string(), {"Content-Type":"text/html"}, True)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s3_conn = S3Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

bucket = s3_conn.get_bucket(s3_bucket_name)

keys = bucket.list()

for key in keys:
    key = bucket.get_key(key.name)
    metadata = key.metadata
    metadata['Content-Type'] = "text/html"
    key.copy(s3_bucket_name, key, metadata=metadata, preserve_acl=True)
```

you have to know that it will replace older metadata, so you should copy all other meta headers (like cache-control....)