# How do you set "Content-Type" when saving to S3 using django-storages with S3boto backend?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto, django-storage

I am using `django-storages` with `s3boto` as a backend.

I have one bucket with two folders - one for `static` and one for `media`.  I achieve this using `django-s3-folder-storage`.

As well as saving to S3 using a model, I also want to implement an image-resize-and-cache function to save the files to S3.  To do this I interact directly with my S3 bucket.  The code works, but the `Content-Type` isn't set on S3.

in iPython:

```
In [2]: from s3_folder_storage.s3 import DefaultStorage

In [3]: s3media = DefaultStorage()

In [4]: s3media
Out[4]: <s3_folder_storage.s3.DefaultStorage at 0x4788780>
```

Test we're accessing the right bucket - `storage_test` is one I created earlier:

```
In [5]: s3media.exists('storage_test')
Out[5]: True

In [6]: s3media.open("test.txt", "w")
Out[6]: <S3BotoStorageFile: test.txt>

In [7]: test = s3media.open("test.txt", "w")

In [8]: test
Out[8]: <S3BotoStorageFile: test.txt>

In [9]: test.key.content_type = "text/plain"

In [10]: test.write("...")

In [11]: test.close()

In [12]: test = s3media.open("test.txt", "w")

In [13]: test.key.content_type
Out[13]: 'binary/octet-stream'
```

I've also tried instead of `In [9]` using `test.key.metadata` and `test.key.set_metadata`.  None of them do it.

How do I set the correct Content-Type?

Answer (score 3):

If you go through the source code in class `S3BotoStorageFile` and function `write`, the header is updated from only 2 places,

1. `upload_headers.update(self._storage.headers)` where `self._storage.headers` is taken from `AWS_HEADERS`
2. `self._storage.default_acl`

And in function `_flush_write_buffer` only `self._storage.headers` is considered. Check for the line `headers = self._storage.headers.copy()`

So updating `test.key.content_type` will not work.

Instead of `test.key.content_type = "text/plain"` at `In [9]:` try using `test._storage.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'`, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use `django-storages >= 1.4` and it automatically guesses the mime types.

Comment: Automatically how? Does it use the mimetypes library?

Comment: @ryan28561 It looks like it uses Python's built-in mimetypes module https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html

Comment: Thanks, when I asked this I was in the middle of a deep dive hunting a bug that was setting my pngs as `image/apng`. Turns out django was using PIL to get the mimetype after the upload and there was a bug in the Pillow 5.4.0.

Answer (score 2):

This is for Boto3 ONLY, not Boto. If you would like to set those headers, you will need to access the object like so, file_ is refereing to a FileField with storage setup to be using Boto3 from django-storages:

```
file_.storage.object_parameters = { 'ContentType': 'text/plain' }
```

NOTE: it requires header names to be camelcase, so `Content-Type` = `ContentType`, `Content-Dispostion` = `ContentDispostion` etc. Hope this helps!

Comment: Be careful with this solution as `storage.object_parameters` is persistent, that is, the same `ContentType` will be set for every file/object after that.
I guess a better approach would be to override the `S3Boto3Storage.get_object_parameters` as [documented](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#settings)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977613/how-do-i-set-the-http-header-for-a-file-in-an-s3-bucket-using-boto-or-another-to), the Content-Type isn't metadata but rather headers that you set up when you upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue - I wanted to set my header for all the files uploaded to S3 using `django-storages`, without relying on the default library approach which is guessing mime type based on the filename.

Please note that you can tweak the way how the header is set and you don't have to have it fixed like I have (my case was specific).

This is what worked for me:

1. Implement custom file manager:

```py
import os

from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage


class ManagedS3BotoS3Storage(S3Boto3Storage):
    def _save(self, name, content):
        cleaned_name = self._clean_name(name)
        name = self._normalize_name(cleaned_name)
        params = self._get_write_parameters(name, content)

        content_type = "application/octet-stream". # Content-Type that I wanted to have for each file
        params["ContentType"] = content_type

        encoded_name = self._encode_name(name)
        obj = self.bucket.Object(encoded_name)
        if self.preload_metadata:
            self._entries[encoded_name] = obj

        content.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
        obj.upload_fileobj(content, ExtraArgs=params)

        return cleaned_name
```

2. Use `ManagedS3BotoS3Storage` in model:

```py
class SomeCoolModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(
        storage=ManagedS3BotoS3Storage(bucket="my-awesome-S3-bucket"),
        upload_to="my_great_path_to_file",
    )
```

3. Run `python manage.py makemigrations`.

That's it, after this all files that I had was uploaded with `Content-Type: "application/octet-stream`