# How can I specify a default content-type for SVG files I upload to Amazon Web Services S3?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, svg, amazon-s3, django-storage

I use SVG files for images in my web app and S3 to serve my static content.

Every time I upload a new file to S3 I have to manually change that file's content-type by going to Properties > Metadata > "Content-Type". I change it to "image/svg+xml" so that web browsers will interpret it as an image. This works fine and all but is getting a bit old as I use a lot of svg files.

So, is there a way to specify that all SVG files should be served with the content-type of "image/svg+xml" by default?

EDIT: For what it's worth, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019737/how-do-you-set-content-type-when-saving-to-s3-using-django-storages-with-s3bot) SO question is related as I am using Django Storages and S3 Boto.

Comment: What does your code look like? Adding metadata during/after upload should be good enough - `metadata.setContentType("image/svg+xml");`